# Python "takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)"

Tags: python, keyword

I want to save keyword arguments passed in in local and pass them to another method later, then I have this error. I could understand why my code came with this error, below is my code.

```
class A():

    def testA(self):
        self.conf = dict(security='BHP')
        self.client = B('FE')
        self.client.addConfigure(**self.conf)

}

class B(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ServerProxy = None

    def run(self):
        if self.flag == 'X':
            self.ServerProxy.runX(self.para)
        elif self.flag == 'Y':
            self.ServerProxy.runY(self.para)
        elif self.flag == 'Z':
            self.ServerProxy.runZ(self.para)


    def addConfigure(self, **kwargs):
        self.para = kwargs
}
```

`runY` defined as in other class

```
def runY(self, **kwargs):
```

why the error pops up as

```
<Fault 1: "<class 'TypeError'>:runY() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)">
```

Comment: What are the extra curly braces for?

Comment: Both. They make your code invalid.

Comment: And how is `ServerProxy` set?

Comment: The code is for company and since internet proxy filter things, I have to change the names of methods and only keep related code. The basic is to store keywords arguments in local and pass to another method without modification, then errors pop up.

Comment: It's easier for others (who regularly follow pep8) to understand your code if you call your instance `server_proxy` instead of `ServerProxy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServerProxy is an instance
You're passing `self.para` as an argument

`runY` is passed these arguments:

```
 runY(<server_proxy_instance>, <self.para>):
```

But is defined like this

```
runY(self, **kwargs):
```

so what name(key) should be given to `self.para` when you shove it into `**kw`?

A simplified version just using a regular function

```
>>> def foo(x, **kw):
...    pass
... 
>>> foo("bar", "baz")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: that is self.conf = dict(security='BHP') I used

Comment: perhaps you mean to pass it like this: `self.ServerProxy.runY(**self.para)`

Comment: I tried in that way, but it says 'security' is unexpected argument

Comment: the server proxy is xmlrpc client

Comment: @Keannylen, If you get "unexpected argument" I'd guess you're missing the `**` parameter on the function definition. Double check that.